# How to use ::before in HTML file

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

This is in the CSS code in CSS File currently:

```
.titletext::before {
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #cc2900 79%, #b3b3b3 21%); 
}
```

But, I want to use it in HTML file, here

```
<h2 class="titletext"> Hii</h2>
```

Because, i want to insert some PHP values in it. How i do this?

This is what i tried:

```
<h2 class="titletext" style::before="background: linear-gradient(90deg, #cc2900 53%, #b3b3b3 47%);">Hii</h2>
```

Comment: You can't. it's not an actual element. It's a pseudo-element. It's for *styling* not actual content,...and it's not a `style` property that can be added to HTML.

Comment: Create a inner element within heading and attach the style to it. Then position the created element absolutely to cover the heading element.

Comment: What you mean @Morpheus sir, I do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the reason you want to use it inline?

The pseudo-selectors `::after` and `::before` can't be used inside `inline-style` attribute.

As an alternative, you could use the style tag before it, but it's not a good workaround to write your CSS inside the HTML file.

With style tag, it would look like this:

```html
<style>
 .titletext::before { 
   background: linear-gradient(90deg, #cc2900 79%, #b3b3b3 21%);  
 } 
</style> 
<h2 class="titletext">Hi</h2>
```

Comment: It is not just "not a good workaround". It is invalid HTML Markup. Since the scope attribute had been deprecated around 7 years ago, the `<style>` tag is only allowed to be inside the head element. IF it works, then only because of the browser auto-correction feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify inline styles for pseudo-elements(like ::before).

The style attribute only defines style properties for a given HTML element. Pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements the are a member of the family of selectors, which don't occur in the attribute so you cant style them inline.

Comment: Alright then, I will use <style></style> in head tag

Comment: Yes, You must use style tag.